# Bootstrap4 and Angular: text-right not working on column

Tags: html, angular, flexbox, bootstrap-4

I must admit that I'm new to bootstrap 4 because used on my old project only 3.3 version that doesn't use flexblox grid system.

Now starting a new project and I'm stuck on this problem:

I just cant give "text-align" css style to col-12 element with native bootstrap class .text-right

I've tried to manually set style="'text-align: right!important'" on html tag and it worked!

I even tried to use a p instead writing text directly in html div-col tag but that's a block element.

Here's the code:

```
<app-footer>
        <div class="container">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-12 text-right">
                    I - Team - Pc System 2019 ©
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
 </app-footer>
```

I just expected to see footer text on the right side of the col but
this is the result:
[image: problem-view]

console analizyng that html element:
[image]

Have you any idea of the problem?
I just want not to apply styling on html element but make native
bootstrap class work properly!

Thanks in advance.

***EDIT:***
Just as you said in comments, maybe this is a problem about bootstrap configuration in my project.

In package.json I have **bootstrap: "^4.2.1"** as dependency.

Then in angular.json we have this:

```
             "styles": [
                        "node_modules/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap-reboot.css",
                        "node_modules/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap-grid.css",
                        [...]
                        "src/dx-styles.scss",
                        "src/styles.scss"
                    ],
```

This project come from a template angular project and is possible that configuration is now right.

Thanks in advance

Comment: do you add `bootstrap.css` in `angular-cli.json` ?\

Comment: can you add your project in stackblitz https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-jgwtme

Comment: did you try margin-left: auto; ?

Comment: Thanks a everyone, i'm going to answer to erikrunia under his answer.
My project use angular7, i don't have angular-cli.json but instead angular.json
@Hameed Syed: it works but i just want to solve this with native bootstrap 4 classes

Answer (score 1):

It seems something is wrong with your bootstrap includes.  A simple fiddle with your code, whilst including boostrap js and css works.

https://jsfiddle.net/qdfy91r5/

```
    <div class="container">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-12 text-right">
                I - Team - Pc System 2019 ©
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

Comment: Hi erikrunia.
Maybe you're right. I'm going to edit original post to show you everithing needed.
Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0):

you can use

```html
div class="container">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-12 col push 5">
                    I - Team - Pc System 2019 ©
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use something like

```
.content{
     display: flex;
     justify-content:end;
 }

div class="container">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-12 col content">
               <p> I - Team - Pc System 2019 ©</p>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

or you can use something like this

```
    div class="container">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-12 col d-flex flex-end">
               <p> I - Team - Pc System 2019 ©</p>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```